# Model student, subject, marks. Application logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Student that has_many Subjects thas has_one Mark. Where should I write logic to sum all student marks from one subject ? Im beginner so any links to documentation or somewhere else are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure Subject only has_one Mark? I would think that a subject would have many Marks. And a Student would have many marks.

Comment: In my case it has only one Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Almost** any time I need to interact with multiple models, I use a plain old Ruby object (aka, a "PORO"). I personally call these 'managers', but I believe it's more common to call them 'service' objects (or some variation). Google 'Rails service objects' and that ought to get you started.